# Biased random number generator function in C

Tags: c, random, probability

Trying to create the following function in C:

```
bool randBool(double bias)
```

which returns either `0` or `1` randomly.

The part that is tripping me up is that I would like to allow for the user to input a "bias" in the range [-1.0, 1.0], which represents the likelihood that the output will be `0` or `1`.

Here are a few examples of how the inputted bias should influence the function:

=======================================================

`randBool(-1.0)` should return `0` 100% of the time.

`randBool(1.0)` should return `1` 100% of the time.

`randBool(-0.5)` is 50% more likely to return `0` than `1`.

`randBool(0.05)` is 5% more likely to return `1` than `0`.

`randBool(0.0)` is no more likely to return `0` than `1`.

=======================================================

I am almost certain that this is a probability problem, but I am not so familiar with the topic, so I am stumped on how to implement this function.

Comment: @mch: That needlessly uses a floating-point function on integers, maps `RAND_MAX` to zero (because the divisor is `RAND_MAX` instead of `RAND_MAX+1`), does not scale the result of `fmod` to -1 to 1 (or conversely, scale the bias to match the result of `fmod`).

Comment: To be clear, when you say 0 is 50% more likely do you mean P(0) = 75% and P(1) = 25%, i.e. an absolute difference of 50% in the probabilities but you'd get three times as many zeroes as ones, or P(0) = 60% and P(1) = 40%, where P(0) is 150% P(1), i.e. a relative difference of 50%, so you'd get 50% more zeroes than ones? (I'm guessing the first, since that's consistent with your 'should return 0/1 100% of the time' examples.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this :

```
bool randBool(double bias) {
    return rand() < ((RAND_MAX + 1.0) * ((bias + 1) / 2));
}
```

The `((bias + 1) / 2)` part is to get the bias in the [0,1] range instead of [-1,1]. That could be avoided if the `bias` parameter is changed to already be in the [0,1] range.

The bias is then defined as the probability of a 1 being returned. With :

- `0.0` (corresponds to your bias `-1.0`) : all zeroes
- `0.25` (corresponds to your bias `-0.5`) : 25% ones, 75% zeroes
- `0.5` (corresponds to your bias `0.0`) : even mix of ones and zeroes
- `0.525` (corresponds to your bias `0.05`) : 52.5% ones, 47.5% zeroes
- `1.0` (corresponds to your bias `1.0`) : all ones

#### NOTES on `RAND_MAX`

- If `RAND_MAX < INT_MAX`, then `RAND_MAX + 1` can be used instead of `RAND_MAX + 1.0`.
- If `RAND_MAX + 1.0` cannot be represented by a `double` without rounding (ref. [Are all integer values perfectly represented as doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655668/are-all-integer-values-perfectly-represented-as-doubles)), then the presented solution is not reliable.

  An approach on such platforms, could be to re-scale the result of `rand()` to a range that can be represented by either an `int` or a `double` (depending on whether you use `RAND_MAX + 1` or `RAND_MAX + 1.0`).

  Or alternatively, use a different random number generator (that doesn't have this issue), which is probably a good idea anyway, given the many low quality implementations of `rand()` out there.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I also realized that a [0,1] range works better for the inputs I will be using anyways.

Comment: Maybe `RAND_MAX + 1.0`? Unless, of course, there's a guarantee that `RAND_MAX < INT_MAX`.

Comment: @pmg: Of course, there is also no guarantee that `RAND_MAX` is less than the point where the result of adding 1 to a `double` produces 1 more than the `double` rather than returning the same `double` due to rounding. In a C implementation with 64-bit `int` and the common IEEE-754 64-bit `double`, `RAND_MAX` could exceed 2^53, after which integer values in `double` are subject to rounding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : I've added some notes to my answer to cover this. Thanks for pointing it out !