# Initializing a long double; printing a different value

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I have the following snippet

```
        cout.precision(30);
        long double d = 85952643841691072928.0;
        cout << d << endl;
```

The print statement outputs  `85952643841691074560`. Why are the last 4 digits before the decimal incorrect? A `long double` should be capable of handling a number of this size?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655668/are-all-integer-values-perfectly-represented-as-doubles

Comment: If a `long double` is 80 bits IEEE 754 on your platform, then the precision is only 18-21 digits.

Comment: You can ask what precision it has, q.v.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116